# Change Excel time format to string as m:ss in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, casting

I've written a bit that imports an excel file into pandas, and puts the information in a dataframe. I want to print the information in a human readable format. As part of doing that, the default time format, hh:mm:ss, needs to be translated to m:ss as the time never goes above an hour.

The data kinda looks like this in excel:

| # | min | cause |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1:30 | db |
| 2 | 2:03 | db |
| 3 | 1:47 | ct |

I need pandas to print the data like this, but the time format is stuck as hh:mm:ss

I've tried type casting it with `pd.to_datetime()` but it throws the error `TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime`. I assume this to mean that it already is a datetime object and can be cast to a string with `dataframename['min'].dt.strftime("%M:%S")`, however it throws a different error: `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`.

Comment: How did you make it a `datetime.time`...?

Comment: I didn't explicitly make it a `datetime.time`, when I brought it in with `pd.read_excel()` it automatically assigned that value to it.

Comment: Also, I see you used `df.dt.strftime...` are you sure you don't want `df['min'].dt.strftime...`?

Comment: That's my mistake in the post, I did have `df['min'].dt.strftime...` and that gives me the AttributeError

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted, but I found a kind of work around. Because pandas interprets the time as hh:mm:00 (no seconds) instead of 00:mm:ss, I can convert the entry to string with `df['min'].astype(str)` and then back to a full datetime with `pd.to_datetime(df['min']).dt.strftime("%H:%M")`. It's not a perfect solution, but since I'm never measuring less than seconds, it should suffice for my needs.